# Contar Multiples Botones con setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

tengo una duda de como hacer correctamente el contar el numero de clicks que realizan en multiples botones de mi .MainActivity

Lo que deseo realizar es que cuente el numero que han hecho de clicks en los botones que se muestra y que cada vez que pinchen en un boton, incremente +1. Al final del conteo quiero que muestre algo en pantalla si es mayor de más de 10 clicks.

Aqui os dejo el codigo que he realizado y me da fallo:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public Button btn01, btn02, btn03, btn04, btn05, btn06, btn07, btn08;

        public int conteo = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.soni);

    // Boton 01
            btn01 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAudi_01);
            btn01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        conteo++;
                    }
            });

    // Boton 02    
            btn02 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAudi_01);
            btn02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        conteo++;
                    }
            });

    // Boton 03
    ...

            if(conteo >=10){
                Log.d("Bien", "Han pinchado mas de 10 veces");
            }else {
                Log.d("Error", "Todavia es menor que 10");}
            }
}
```

Al final, el Log no muestra nada de los mensajes. Parece como si no tuviese en cuenta **conteo**

### **ACTUALIZADO:**

En cada botón carga un Audio diferente como podréis ver en **mp_01.start();**, en el botón 2 carga **mp_02.start();** y así sucesivamente hasta 8 botones.

```
// Boton 01
btn01 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnAudi_01);
final MediaPlayer mp_01 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonido01);
        btn01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    conteo =  conteo+1;
                    if(conteo>10){
                        Log.d("Bien", "Le hemos dado " + conteo);                       
                        conteo = 0;
                    }else{
                       Log.d("Error", "Muestro AUDIO");
                       mp_01.start();
                    }
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la condicion que muestra la cantidad de clicks no esta dentro de un evento, si le mandas como esta nunca te va a mostrar ya que solo se ejecutaria al abrir la app. al crear los componentes...

te recomiendo crear un metodo

```
private boolean verificarConteo(){
      if(conteo >=10){
            Log.d("Bien", "Han pinchado mas de 10 veces");
        }else {
            Log.d("Error", "Todavia es menor que 10");}
        }
}
```

y ese metodo llamarlo al evento onClickListener de los botones luego de

```
 conteo++;
```

Comment: Tengo una consulta que hacerte. Cuando le tiro el Bien, no hay ningun problema de que se repita el Log.d("Bien"). El problema lo tengo en el else, el Log.d("Error"), ya que necesito que cargue un audio correspondiendo al boton que le haya pinchado. Por ejemplo: Te he dejado nuevo Codigo para que puedas comprobar, gracias por tu rapida respuesta compañero

Comment: puedes pasar un parametro en el metodo verificarConteo(String nombreBoton)  y ese al llamar en cada boton le pasas el monde o id del boton.. y dentro del else le puedes hacer una serie de if para que dentro de ello le pongas los audios correspondientes

Comment: para una mejor respuesta marca la respuesta como correcta. ya que lo que tu comentas es una nueva pregunta. diferente a la expuesta. saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para esto lo recomendable es crear únicamente un `OnClickListener` en el cual al dar click se aumente el valor de la variable `conteo`  y este listener asignarlo a todos los botones:

```
private int conteo = 0;

View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {          
      if(conteo > 10){            
        muestra();
       //Reinicia contador.
         conteo++;
      }else{
        //Aumenta contador.
         conteo++;
      }
    }
};
```

Creado el listener simplemente asignalo a los botones:

```
    btn01.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    btn02.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    btn03.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar el metodo [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) y [getTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) que es independiente para cada vista, con el cual puedes asignar un valor extra. Por ejemplo:

***Implementa la interfaz del OnClick de View.***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Agrega los listeners a cada boton:

```
btn01.setOnClickListener(this);
btn02.setOnClickListener(this);
```

. . . etc...

y sobreescribes el metodo de la interfaz:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getTag() == null)
        v.setTag(0); // Valor por defecto

    v.setTag(((int)v.getTag() + 1)); // Aumentamos 1 al contador

    if((int)v.getTag() > 10){
        // Reinicias el Tag a su valor por defecto, si lo prefieres
        // v.setTag(0); // Valor por defecto
        Log.d("Bien", "Han pinchado mas de 10 veces");
    }
    else{
        // Reproduce el audio segun el id del boton
        startAudioAlert(v.getId);
        Log.d("Bien", "Todavia es menor que 10");
    }

}

private void startAudioAlert(int id){
    switch(id){
       case R.id.btnAudi_01:
          mp_01.start();
          break;
       case R.id.btnAudi_02:
          mp_02.start();
          break;
    }
}
```

Y así con cada id de los botones y su audio correspondiente.